# Best software for monitoring/alerting based on log files?

Tags: monitoring

I'm setting up an iMac to use as a server that will be doing some automated file copying/moving via the Hazel app, in conjunction with some shell scripts.  It's a system for dropping off files, which then get processed, copied to a couple archive disk arrays and then moved to a NAS.  It's very important that if anything goes wrong, or looks suspicious, I (and whoever else) can be alerted ASAP.

Hazel writes to a dedicated log file, and the shell scripts are writing to their own file, as well as the Hazel file.  I'm using some functions to write standardized error/warning messages to the log files.

I'd like to run a program/daemon/whatever on the server that monitors the logs and can keep track of errors/warnings and send alerts. E-mail alerts are the bare necessity.  Mobile push and/or SMS would be cool, as would intelligent alerting such as noticing if I don't mark an alert as "read" or "resolved" and continuing to alert me.

I'm willing to use a web service (preferably but not necessarily free) to help with this.

Any suggestions?